# Lower than max resolutions not scaling to full screen

Tags: resolution, 13.04, i915

When applications or I manually select lower resolutions it will only show in the top left corner of my screen with the correct amount of pixels.  There are streaking colors coming off to the right.  This happened to me on some older versions and was correct through the 11 and 12 series.

```
sudo lshw -c video
 *-display:0             
description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 03
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:dff00000-dff7ffff ioport:ec38(size=8) memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:dfec0000-dfefffff
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
   description: Display controller
   product: Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2.1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
   version: 03
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:dff80000-dfffffff
```

I'm not sure if its supposed to be showing that second unclaimed monitor or what but it seems like the correct driver is enabled.  I tried to look for the xconf in the normal place but nothing was there so I guess that isn't around anymore.

As a side note scaling is enabled in the bios and works properly for the bios screen alternate install CD.

Does anyone have any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Tried with bios scaling turned off and got the same exact result as with it enabled.  Did not scale.

Answer (score 0):

This should be solving your problem.

http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/04/ubuntu-screen-custom-resolution.html

Comment: Thank you thefourtheye.  In the past I have had to use the commands you linked when all my resolutions weren't showing up.  In this case all of the applicable screen resolutions / refresh rates are showing in the display settings applet.  The issue is only with resolutions lower than 1400x1050 scaling to the full size of this monitor.

Comment: You mean, after executing those commands, you are getting all the modes applicable?

Comment: No all the modes were in there by default after install.  It seems like the resolution / refresh for the modes is correct but they do not have switches for scaling.  I think xrandr has ways to set the scaling mode for each resolution but for some reason.  I checked out the manpage but I'm not getting any luck inputting the command correctly.